# Populate class based on attribute value

Tags: python

I have data that is streamed in a repeating fashion that I need to apply business logic to before populating a @dataclass.

The data class has the following structure:

```
class Foo:
   color: str
   engine: int
   petrol: int
   diesel: int
```

The data consists of a enum color, and two pairs of two digit numbers streamed a single digit at a time.

```
Red, 3, 1, 4, 5, Blue, 2, 2, 7, 5, Orange, 5, 2, 6, 8 etc...
```

Red is assigned to color attribute, 31 is assigned to engine attribute.

If the color attribute is Red, Blue or Yellow then the last two digits (45) are assigned to petrol attribute.

If the color attribute is Orange or Green then the last two digits (45) are assigned to diesel attribute.

I tried this:

```
digits = 0
positional_counter = 0

# Set first attribute color
if value in ["Red", "Blue", "Orange", "Green"]:
     self.foo.color = value
     positional_counter += 1

# Set second attribute - joining the digits
if positional_counter == 1:
     digits = value * 10
     positional_counter += 1
if positional_counter == 2:
     self.foo.engine = digits + value
     digits = 0
     positional_counter += 1

# Whether the second set of digits is set against petrol or diesel depends on color attrib
if self.foo.color in ["Red", "Blue"]:
   if positional_counter == 3:
       digits = value * 10
       positional_counter += 1
   if positional_counter == 4:
       self.foo.petrol = digits + value
       positional_counter = 0
if self.foo.color in ["Orange", "Green"]:
   if positional_counter == 3:
       digits = value * 10
       positional_counter += 1
   if positional_counter == 4:
       self.foo.diesel = digits + value
       positional_counter = 0
```

Is there a better way to do this? The above code looks unreadable and messy. It is also possible that the data may start streaming on a value other than a color enum - in which case the first one or two values can be skipped using until a color enum is encountered to set start position.

Comment: Having one class whose instances never use one attribute or the other is a bit suspect. `Foo` should replace `petrol` and `diesel` with a single `fuel` attribute, and `Diesel` and `Petrol` would be two subclasses that indicate the type of fuel the `fuel` attribute represents.

Comment: Then, the color tells you which subclass to instantiate.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the nature of the stream data.  The code expects value to be an instance of either `str` or `int`.  Will the stream actually supply items of type 'int`, or will this be a stream from eg: a text file, where we must also convert the values to `int` when they are not `in ["Red", "Blue", "Orange", "Green"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have two classes, `Diesel` and `Petrol`, that both subclass `Vehicle`. The base class just worries about *amount* of fuel; the subclasses carry information about what *kind* of fuel is carried.

```
@dataclass
class Vehicle:
    color: ColorType
    engine: int
    fuel: int


@dataclass
class Diesel(Vehicle):
    pass


@dataclass
class Petrol(Vehicle):
    pass
```

Then define a dict to map color to fuel type:

```
d = {
      Red: Diesel,
      Blue: Diesel,
      Yellow: Diesel,
      Green: Petrol,
      Orange: Petrol
    }
```

Preprocess the data before worrying about instantiating anything

```
def process_data(d) -> Iterable[tuple[Color, int, int]]:
    # Turn [Red, 3, 1, 4, 5, ...] into [(Red, 31, 45), ...]
```

Then simply use the dict you defined earlier to choose which class to instantiate based on color:

```
data = [Red, 3, 1, 4, 5, Blue, 2, 2, 7, 5, Orange, 5, 2, 6, 8]
for color, engine, fuel in process_data(data):
    obj = d[color](color, engine, fuel)
    ...
```